# Registering a custom NSUrlProtocol in MonoTouch

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I am building an iOS app using MonoTouch and attempting to implement a custom NSUrlProtocol.

When I register my own protocol implementation, I get the following error:

> WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the
>   webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:
>   delegate:  *** -canInitWithRequest: only
>   defined for abstract class.  Define
>   -[Foo.Network.NetworkServices+TestProtocol canInitWithRequest:]!

Any thoughts on what could be causing this?

Here is the code:

```
//Registering the protocol    
NSUrlProtocol.RegisterClass(new Class(typeof(TestProtocol)));

public class TestProtocol : NSUrlProtocol
{
    public TestProtocol ()
    {
        this.Client = new TestProtocolClient(); 
    }       

    public override bool CanInitWithRequest (NSUrlRequest request)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public class TestProtocolClient : NSUrlProtocolClient
{
    public override void DataLoaded (NSUrlProtocol protocol, NSData data)
    {
    }

    public override void FailedWithError (NSUrlProtocol protocol, NSError error)
    {
    }

    public override void ReceivedResponse (NSUrlProtocol protocol, NSUrlResponse response, NSUrlCacheStoragePolicy policy)
    {
    }

    public override void Redirected (NSUrlProtocol protocol, NSUrlRequest redirectedToEequest, NSUrlResponse redirectResponse)
    {
    }

    public override void CachedResponseIsValid (NSUrlProtocol protocol, NSCachedUrlResponse cachedResponse)
    {
    }

    public override void FinishedLoading (NSUrlProtocol protocol)
    {
    }

    public override void ReceivedAuthenticationChallenge (NSUrlProtocol protocol, NSUrlAuthenticationChallenge challenge)
    {
    }

    public override void CancelledAuthenticationChallenge (NSUrlProtocol protocol, NSUrlAuthenticationChallenge challenge)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NSUrlProtocol support in MonoTouch is currently broken.

It will be fixed in the next beta release (MonoTouch 5.3.3). There is also a [sample](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/monotouch-5.4/ImageProtocol) available to show how it works (but it will obviously not work until MonoTouch 5.3.3 is out).

Xamarin's [support](http://support.xamarin.com/) can usually give you preview builds if it's an urgent matter.